# Can a tail call be optimized to fall through?

Tags: c++

Given

```
int foo(float f) {...}

Int bar(int I) { return foo(i); }
```

Would it be legal/possible for a compiler to place `bar` directly before `foo` in the binary image so that the call isn't even a jump, but just continuing at the next instruction? Or would doing that have to violate something that the standards require?

Could the compile do that where the wrapper function end up being a noop? (I.g. where the two different symbols would end up pointing to the same address.)

The situation that prompted this thought was thinking about what an `extern "c"` wrapper around a C++ method would actually end up looking like at the machine code level, particularly in the case where C++ ABI can't match the C ABI.

Comment: What does your particular compiler say? `extern "C"` is usually just a way of suppressing name mangling more than anything. Does it have that dramatic an impact on the way things are optimized? A lot of compilers will inline things like this unless `foo()` is called in other places.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion

Comment: @tadman I'm wondering about what the standards allow, not what compilers implement.

Comment: @RyanHaining I'm actually wondering about the *exact* opposite case. Inlineing would create a second copy of the called function. What I'm thinking of would tack the body of the calling function in front of the canonical instance of the called function.

Comment: Although it's all too easy to over-simplify here, the standards generally shy away from mandating specifics like you're talking about, and instead give the implementers considerable latitude, provided the [same "observable behaviour" results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule). That is, so long as `bar(n)` produces the expected result under all defined cases, it's valid.

Comment: I'd expect that a lot of compilers would see `bar()` as an entirely extraneous call, and really what it ends up being is a call to `foo()` with the appropriate cast applied.

Comment: @tadman Tail call optimization has some observable effects and is explicitly allowed. Also, in part, my question is would that have observable effects? E.g. If the prefix has zero length, then comparing the two functions for equality might be seen?

Comment: Do you have a code example of how the inlined vs. non-inlined versions would produce observably different results? If you're involving function pointers that is going to complicate things significantly, necessarily, same as using pointers to local variables does.

Comment: @tadman the compiler can only inline `bar` in TUs where it's implementation is available (or in the linker). Cross language calls or closed source libraries aren't that.

Comment: That sort of goes without saying.

Comment: @tadman say if `foo` and `bar` take the same types, but in some cases `bar` is a no-op (e.g. on some architectures), then somewhere do `auto ptr = &foo; ... cout << (ptr == &bar);`?

Comment: You may force the compiler to generate a callable function version of it by doing that. That still doesn't preclude specific instances of a call from being inlined.

Comment: I believe it's legal for two functions to have the same address.  Some implementations actually combine seemingly unrelated functions if they just happen to have ended up with byte-for-byte identical machine code (e.g. look for "COMDAT folding" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/opt-optimizations))

Comment: *"Would it be legal/possible for [X]"* -- The as-if rule makes many optimizations legal and possible, given suitable conditions. A better question might be asking if there are cases where X is *not* legal.